# Unable to execute WebIOPi

Tags: gpio, serial, webiopi

I have been working with a Raspberry Pi 2 for little time. I was working with serial devices using `webiopi`, everything was good and running nicely. However, a few days ago I plugged in the Raspberry, like always, and I tried to run `webiopi` with the following command:

```
sudo webiopi -d -c /etc/webiopi/config
```

After doing that, I got this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

I don't even know why is looking for that serial device, I'm not using Arduino, I'm using the on-board GPIO.

Do you know how to solve this? I have tried everything I found on the web, but with no results.

Comment: can you share you `/etc/webiopi/config` file?
Also try using this patch-version RPi-2 : [Double-bind](https://github.com/doublebind/raspi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong, in my script.py file I was using ttyACM0 instead of ttyAMA0. A dumb mistake I know...

Comment: Those mistakes are the drive of the human progression. It's the thing we call "learning". And you also practiced a second way to increase our knowledge: you told us about your mistake. I can not understand why someone has downvoted your answer. You saved me hours of blind searching on a similiar mistake. Thank you. I'll upvote your answer to neutralize the downvote. Plz could you mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm glad I saved you those hours, thank you for the upvote. I can mark my answer as correct tomorrow, but I will.